# Someone knows how to install Android Studio for all users to avoid every user download the same sdk?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a computer that is used by multiple developers.

Everytime when a new developer used the computer, Android Studio will download the sdk to the user profile.

Could I set a sdk path for all users to prevent this duplication of information?

Comment: put some code that you try..

Comment: You can but it will depend on your system. You should try [The Google Machine](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20path%20variable%20for%20android%20studio) first